# When are powers of primitive elements still primitive elements

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

This question is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75666/for-which-k-do-the-kth-powers-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-give-a-basis-for/) and is tangentially related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157784/can-we-always-find-a-primitive-element-that-is-a-square/157956#157956).

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of fields. Pick $\alpha \in L \setminus K$ and consider the simple extension $K(\alpha)/K$. Let $p$ be a prime not equal to the characteristic of $K$. Suppose that $K(\alpha^p) \neq K(\alpha)$ then by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory there is a $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha^p)=\alpha^p$. In particular $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a solution to the equation $x^p-\alpha^p$ so we have that $\sigma(\alpha)=\zeta \alpha$ with $\zeta$ a $p$-th primitive root of unity. Since there are only finitely many automorphisms, there can only be finitely many primes $p$ for which $K(\alpha^p) \neq K(\alpha)$.

This shows that for infinitely many primes $p$ the $p$-th power of a primitive element of a separable extension is still primitive. I feel that this result is likely still true in the case of an inseparable simple extension. But it's clear that my proof will not generalize to this case. So my question is if a similar result is true and how it's proved.

As a last aside, I'd be happy to see any references on these sorts of questions even as just an exercise in a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can reduce this to the separable case.

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension, and $\alpha \in L - K$. Let $\rm{char} K = p$. Let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $\alpha^{p^n}$ is separable over $K$. We claim that for any prime $q \neq p$,
$$K(\alpha^q) = K(\alpha) \Leftrightarrow K(\alpha^{qp^n}) = K(\alpha^{p^n})$$

Forward side is obvious. For the backward side, note that the assumption implies that $K(\alpha^q)$ contains $K(\alpha^{p^n})$. Then we know that $K(\alpha^q)$ must be the same as $K(\alpha^{p^k})$, $k \leq n$. But if $K(\alpha^q) = K(\alpha^{p^k})$, by noting that $gcd(q,p^k) = 1$, we see that this is also the same as $K(\alpha)$.