# If $a \in L-k $ satisfies $k(a^n)=L$ (for all $n \geq 1$), then $L/k$ is Galois?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Let $k \subsetneq L$ be a finite separable field extension, and let $a \in L-k$ satisfy: For every $n \geq 1$, $k(a^n)=L$.

In other words, all the non-zero powers of the primitive element $a$ are also primitive elements.

> Is there something interesting to say about such an extension? Should it be Galois?

**Partial answer:** According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307406/when-are-powers-of-primitive-elements-still-primitive-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, if the extension is of prime degree, and if there exist infinitely many $m$'s such that $k(b^m) \neq L=k(b)$, then $k \subsetneq L$ is not Galois.

But I am asking about the opposite direction, namely, if only finitely many (= more precisely, zero) $2 \leq m$'s are such that $k(b^m) \subsetneq k(b)=L$, then $k \subseteq L$ is Galois? Can we reverse the argument in that question?

---

**Special case $k=\mathbb{Q}$:** Can one find $a \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}-\mathbb{Q}$
satisfying $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(a^2)=\mathbb{Q}(a^3)=\ldots$?

The following are two non-examples for $k=\mathbb{Q}$:

**(1)** In the spirit of the comment for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060132/a-b-in-bark-such-that-ka-kb-kab?noredirect=1#comment6310162_3060132) question, notice that here taking $a=p^{\frac{1}{m}}$ for some (positive) prime $p \geq 2$ and fixed $m \geq 2$ will not help, since $a^m=(p^{\frac{1}{m}})^m=p$ so $\mathbb{Q}(a^m)=\mathbb{Q}(p)=\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

**(2)** $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ will not help; indeed, $a^2+a+1=0$, 
so $a^2=-a-1$, then $a^3=-a^2-a=-(-a-1)-a=1$, so $\mathbb{Q}(a^3)=\mathbb{Q}(1)=\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: A simple example take $a=1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Oh, of course.. thank you. Is it true that also any $a=1+p^{\frac{1}{m}}$ will work, where $p \geq 2$ is prime and $m \geq 2$? (Perhaps one has to be careful, and not all such $p$ and $m$ will work).

Comment: No It won't. As you explained in you question.

Comment: @mouthetics, please, is it possible to find $b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ such that: $\mathbb{Q}(b^n)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (for all $n \geq 2$), and also $b-a \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Well, $b=1+2\sqrt2$ =)

Comment: @KennyLau, very good example! Please, any ideas if such extensions are necessarily Galois? (at least if we further assume that $[L:k]$ is prime).

Comment: What if $k = \mathbb{Q}$, $L = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, $a = 1 + \sqrt[3]{2}$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler, thank you. It is not Galois, but still satisfies the condition $\mathbb{Q}(a^n)=L$...

Comment: There are a lot of example for which the extension is not Gaois. Take the real root, say $\alpha$, of any irreducible polynomial $x^3+ax+b$ with $ab\neq 0$. Then $\alpha$ satisfies the property but $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not Galois.

Comment: @mouthetics, thank you for your more general example.

Comment: Just one addition take the polynomial so that the other two roots are not real to be sure they are not in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thanks. The following question is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329213/criteria-for-a-prime-degree-field-extension-to-be-galois?noredirect=1&lq=1